# Readyapi property expansion not working in kafka Connection Settings options

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I am running readyapi from command line and passing a properties file as an system option.
The properties are successfully resolved in most of the cases (rest api endpoint, database connection), the only problem seems to be in the kafka configuration, specifically in the
"Connection Settings" tab.

The command executed is:

```
"path\to\testrunner.bat" "-sTest Suite" "-cTest Case" -r -j -f${WORKSPACE} "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML -EDEFAULT -Dsoapui.properties="properties.txt" path\to\readyapi-project.xml
```

I have tried to access the property with all the possible options provided here: https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/properties/expansion.html#scopes.

Can you please advice on how can I dynamically pass the properties to the kafka connection settings?

Comment: Not sure if you are still living with this problem. Where have you stored the connection properties? Have you tried storing them in properties file which you are passing from command line?

Comment: Hello @Rao and sorry for the late response, yes as I described here I'm passing the properties file location as an env variable when executing the script from command line using the param:

`-Dsoapui.properties="properties.txt"`



*It's not a .txt file, that's just an example*